# How to specify connection details for SSDT unit tests when run in Azure Devops yaml build pipeline

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, sql-server-data-tools

I am using SSDT unit tests for my database project. They run no problem from Visual Studio.

I would like these tests to run when I run my build pipeline on Azure DevOps, but when  it is unable to connect. I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 110003;Invalid user or password.

The yaml for my test is as follows:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
        testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
        testAssemblyVer2: |
          **\*test*.dll
          !**\*TestAdapter.dll
          !**\obj\**
        searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
```

Is there anything in particular that needs to go in the app.config file to get this to work? Note: I'm using SQL authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the SSDT unit tests connects to the database server on your local machine, the azure devops pipeline will fail, for the hosted agents cannot communicate with your local machine.

In this case you should [create a self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) on your local machine, and run your pipeline on the self-hosted agent by defining the pool as your local agent pool in yaml pipeline.

If you are using other cloud database server like azure sql server. You can check if the connectionString in App.config is correct, and provide the correct **User ID** and **Password**. The connectionString in app.config file is like below example

[image]

If you want to avoid storing sensitive information in a connection string in app.config. You can store the connectionString in a [secret variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#secret-variables) in your pipeline.

And use tokens `connectionString="#{sqlDbTestConnectionString}#"` in app.config in place of real connection strings.

Then add [replace token task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) before VsTest task in your pipeline to replace the tokens `#{sqlDbTestConnectionString}#` in app.config with the real connectionString defined in secret variable.

You can check [this blog](https://medium.com/@shanmugamchinnappa/securely-configuring-azure-devops-pipeline-for-sql-unit-testing-be81f4c2cc10) for more information.